# Retrieving a single type of objects from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small problem with Firebase. I have an object representing a user information and other objects representing entrances and exits. The problem is that I want to extract only the user objects stored on Firebase. Is there any way to do it?

Thank you.

this is my Json

```
{
  "Entradas-123456789E": {
    "Entradas : 13-2-2017": {
      "DetallesMon Mar 13 12:03:17 GMT+01:00 2017": {
        "user": {
          "dni": "123456789E"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Salidas-123456789E": {
    "Salidas : 13-2-2017": {
      "DetallesMon Mar 13 20:06:46 GMT+01:00 2017": {
        "user": {
          "dni": "123456789E"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Usuario_123456789E": {
    "dni": "123456789E",
    "lastname": "Prueba Prueba2",
    "name": "Mireia",
    "password: "######"
  },
  "Usuario_536881138E": {
    "dni": "53688138E",
    "lastname": "Mheb",
    "name": "Antonia",
    "password:"######"
  }
}
```

**this is the Code**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private Intent takePictureIntent;
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef;
private String pathFotoTemporal;
private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
private View view;
private String key;

//Expandable list Adapter
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

//Users
private List <User> items = new ArrayList<>();

//Obejeto a pasar
User user = new User();
String password;


//Buttons
private EditText TextPass;
private EditText TextDNI;
private Button fichar;

// Adding child data
List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    LeerFirebase();

    //Button
    TextPass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.IdpasswordUser);
    //TextDNI = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.DNI);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    //expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    //Write in database mesage myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");

    //Call Button fichar
    fichar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fichar);
    fichar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            key = TextDNI.getText().toString();
            password = TextPass.getText().toString();

            //SuperUser
            if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("********")&&password.equalsIgnoreCase("*******")){
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).EditarUsuario();
                fichar.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                TextPass.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                TextDNI.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            }else{
                LeerFirebase();
            }

            //Para pasar de fragment hay que comprobar el dni y el password
            /*((MainActivity) getActivity()).AbrirFichar();
            fichar.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            TextPass.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);*/

        }
    });
    return view;
}

private void LeerFirebase() {
    myRef = database.getReference("Usuario" +"_"+ key+"/password");
    //+"/password"
    // Read from the database
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            password = TextPass.getText().toString();
            if(password.equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
                //Pasamos por pantalla
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"El usuario introducido es correcto",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Pasamos al otro Fragment
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).AbrirFichar(TextDNI.getText().toString());
                fichar.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                TextPass.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                TextDNI.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"El usuario introducido o la Contraseña no son correctos ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hay un error de lectura ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

//On start button is Visible
@Override
public void onStart() {
    final Button fichar = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.fichar);
    EditText getpassword = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.IdpasswordUser);
    fichar.setVisibility(getView().VISIBLE);
    getpassword.setVisibility(getView().VISIBLE);
    super.onStart();
}


//List Adapter
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("User Name");

    //Firebase carga

    DatabaseReference ListaRef = database.getReference();

    // Read from the database
    ListaRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.

            items.clear();
            User usuarios;

            for( DataSnapshot i : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                usuarios = i.getValue(User.class);
                items.add(usuarios);
                top250.add(" " + usuarios.getName() + " " + usuarios.getLastname());
            }
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Se han bajado " + items.size() + " Usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error descargando las recetas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
        List<String> top = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Falta corregir no saca nada
        for(int i = 0 ; i < top250.size(); i++){
            if (top250.get(i).isEmpty()||top250.equals(null)||top250.get(i).equals(null)||top250.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("null null")){
                System.out.println("Noooo");
        }else{
            top.add(top250.get(i));
        }
    }
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top); // Header, Child data
}
}
```

Comment: When you are dealing with a Turing-complete language such as Java, the answer to the question "Is there any way to do it?" is almost always "yes".

Comment: Hello Mireia, welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are more likely to get a helpful response if you improve your question.  Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For example, you should remove all your code that isn't related to the firebase query, and make your title more descriptive, and describe what you've tried and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: Mireia, te recomiendo que hagas preguntas detalladas, en este foro no llevan bien que la gente pida ayuda sin saber que es lo que necesitan. Lo ideal es que vengas con una pregunta concisa y así la gente sepa como ayudarte. Hoy en día, de una forma u otra, podrás hacer lo que quieras.

Answer (score 1):

The Json changed and found

```
{
  "Records" : {
    "Enters" : {
      "Entradas-5123445B" : {
        "Entradas : 15-2-2017" : {
          "DetallesWed Mar 15 10:08:59 GMT+01:00 2017" : {
            "user" : {
              "dni" : "5123445B"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Entradas-5128445A" : {
        "Entradas : 15-2-2017" : {
          "DetallesWed Mar 15 10:11:17 GMT+01:00 2017" : {
            "user" : {
              "dni" : "5128445A"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Exits" : {
      "Salidas-5123445B" : {
        "Salidas : 15-2-2017" : {
          "DetallesWed Mar 15 10:09:46 GMT+01:00 2017" : {
            "user" : {
              "dni" : "5123445B"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "Usuario_5123445B" : {
      "dni" : "5123445B",
      "lastname" : "Apellido Apellidos",
      "name" : "Prueba",
      "password" : "######"
    },
    "Usuario_5128445A" : {
      "dni" : "5128445A",
      "lastname" : "Apellido mwk",
      "name" : "NjdNom",
      "password" : "######"
    }
  }
}
```

**And the code**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    private View view;
    private String key;

    //Expandable list Adapter
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    //Users
    private List <User> items = new ArrayList<>();

    //Obejeto a pasar
    User user = new User();
    String password;


    //Botones
    private EditText TextPass;
    private EditText TextDNI;
    private Button fichar;

    // Adding child data
    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        LeerFirebase();

        //Botones
        TextPass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.IdpasswordUser);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //Llamamos al boton fichar
        fichar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fichar);
        fichar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                key = TextDNI.getText().toString();
                password = TextPass.getText().toString();
                //SuperUsuario
                if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("######")&&password.equalsIgnoreCase("#########")){
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).EditarUsuario();
                    fichar.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                    TextPass.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                    TextDNI.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                }else{
                    LeerFirebase();
                }

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void LeerFirebase() {
        myRef = database.getReference("Usuario" +"_"+ key+"/password");
        // Read from the database
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                password = TextPass.getText().toString();
                if(password.equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
                    //Pasamos por pantalla
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"El usuario introducido es correcto",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Pasamos al otro Fragment
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).AbrirFichar(TextDNI.getText().toString());
                    fichar.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                    TextPass.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                    TextDNI.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"El usuario introducido o la Contraseña no son correctos ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hay un error de lectura ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    //Al iniciarse crea el boton Visible
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        final Button fichar = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.fichar);
        EditText getpassword = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.IdpasswordUser);
        fichar.setVisibility(getView().VISIBLE);
        getpassword.setVisibility(getView().VISIBLE);
        super.onStart();
    }


    //List Adapter
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("User Name");

        //Firebase carga

        DatabaseReference ListaRef = database.getReference("Users");

        // Read from the database
        ListaRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                items.clear();
                User usuarios;

                for( DataSnapshot i : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    usuarios = i.getValue(User.class);
                    items.add(usuarios);
                    top250.add(" " + usuarios.getName() + " " + usuarios.getLastname());
                }
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Se han bajado " + items.size() + " Usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error descargando las recetas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250);
    }
}
```

**Thanks, it works. I leave the result in case someone needs to get information in a list with firebase already knows how to do it.**

Answer (score 0):

You should sort your answer in two parent arrays, you could call them "users" and "records" if you like, then within each one you put the respective records and the ones you require

Like this:

[image: json structure]

Then with Firebase you can extrac only the "users" object, and parsing with gson in other objet, a iteration with each user that you need.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and advice, I will try to change the way of structuring the Json. Forgive my English, as you can see, it's not very good.

Comment: Dont worry, remember that you can always use stackoverflow in Spanish